# SVG as data URI not rendering

Tags: css, svg, data-uri

It's probably just a syntax error but I can't find any thorough references on this kind of usage. Chrome is overstriking my background property, so I've obviously offended something.

http://jsfiddle.net/YbA39/2/

I want what's in the red box (an svg css background) to render just like the inline svg in the html. Simple, right?

Don't say it can't be done! My inspiration is this: http://jsfiddle.net/estelle/SJjJb/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't escaped the '#' characters in the url() syntax. And it's 'viewBox' not 'viewbox'.

Here's something that works: http://jsfiddle.net/YbA39/3/ (just a quick urlescaped string).

Comment: Well, yes, that does work. But it doesn't really explain why my example doesn't work. Chrome20, Firefox13, and Opera12 all support unencoded SVG as a data URI. (Only IE9 requires base64 or URI encoding, sticking tightly to the spec). For proof, look at the second 'estelle' fiddle. It doesn't escape its '#' characters, and also isn't URI-encoded, and it works fine. Why? What's the difference between mine and estelle's? Capitalizing the "b" in viewbox (good catch!) doesn't fix it...

Comment: Right. Oops, I thought I'd checked that! I will stick to URI encoding. Just out of curiosity: any plans to support unencoded data-URI in Opera, a la Chrome? From what I can tell the data-URI spec hasn't been touched since 1998. Is it ever going to be extended?

Comment: Thanks for the 'encoding thing'. I used the http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ to encode the whole <svg ... /> thing so now it works well except IE (even v.11)

Answer (score 1):

The newlines in the declaration were breaking it. Removing all the newlines fixes it in all but IE, which requires base64 or URI encoding:

http://jsfiddle.net/YbA39/4/